# Pass json object from one HTML page to another

Tags: html, json

I am opening a page using window.open(). Is there a way to pass a JSON object from the parent to the child page? Ofcourse writing data to a cookie from the parent and reading that same cookie from the new page might be an option. Any simpler ways?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

```
var options = {foo:'foo'};
var myURL="http://localhost";
window.open( myURL + "/?options=" + JSON.stringify(options) );
```

didn't test that code before, try this, you can access it through GET

Comment: It didn't work. When I try to read it in the child page I get an error message that the object is undefined.

Comment: I knew I could use a query string. I didn't want to do that because the data is more than the query string can handle :(

Comment: then make some form you could submit, or save the data to file, and read it from ...

Answer (score 1):

I see there are several ways to do this:

1. Cookies. Write values to cookies and read it in the opened window.
2. Pass as a part of url hash: window.open(url + '#' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json));
3. I would try to

   winRef = window.open(...);

   winRef.postMessage(...);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

I didn't try the third option, but it might be a nice alternative to 1 and 2.