# Pass json object to another html

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I have a simple Flask application with just one table.
So python code is irrelavantly simple:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    items = long_db_request()
    return render_template("index.html", items=items)


@app.route('/extended')
def extended():
    return render_template("animals.html")
```

And items is a huge JSON object.

I created a table which reflects that data:

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center">id</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">creation time</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">name</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">animals</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">number</th>
    </tr>
        {% for item in items %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ item.id }} </td>
                <td> {{ item.time }} </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{url_for('extended', name=item.id )}}"> {{ item.name }} </a>
                </td>
                <td> {{item.group}} </td>
                <td>{{ item.group|length }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

The table looks like:
[image]

As you can see, column animal contains a lof of object which makes it all difficult to percieve.
I want it to be like this
[image]

which is a lot easier to get. And `show animals` is a link to another page, where a pure json exists.

How can I achieve this?

I followed the doc of jinja2 and Flask and found method [url_for()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) but in that case I have to pass all my json in query which is unacceptable..

How can I jump from first image to exellent nice view of the second one?

working code with the first picture is place [here](https://bitbucket.org/ivanwolodin/pass-json-from-html-to-html/)

Thank you very much in advance!

P.S. I only saw [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112573/pass-json-object-from-one-html-page-to-another) here with rellevant topic, but it does not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing all the animals (e.g. cats) from one view to another, just pass the category `cats` to the next page.

The view function for the next page then selects all cats from the json, and passes the `cats` then to the detailed view.

So, on you overview page, you render links like `species.html?cats` (and so on), and when somebody clicks on these links the view function selects all cats, and then passes them into a `render_template("species.html", species=cats)` view.

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow. In above code, you have access to your items object which is the JSON object. At some point you generate or load this data. Just make sure you can access this object from both your home and your extend routes. And in your extended routes you do not pass in the complete object to your template, but only the necessary data. You can work with JSON in Python via the json module.

Comment: @J. G. I get `items` from very long db request, so it is only reacheable within home() view and then in index.html. So I changed code a little to make it clearer

Comment: That is no reason :-) Just put the db request on module level or stick it into a "get_data" function, which you access from both view functions. If you are afraid that you have to load the data twice, you could use some caching. That is much easier than it sounds. Don't be afraid to do the right thing :-)

Comment: I created a small script which illustrates how a simple cache can be implemented... the first time it takes long, but all subsequent calls return almost at once ... https://gist.github.com/jugmac00/8f722ce20b315ac66b0e69254827b6ee

Comment: @J. G. Thank you, is there a way to solve the task another way, not using url_for() and try js somehow?..

Comment: Well, you could load the complete data set, but hide the complete data, and show only the "headings" - or you can use React or Vue or Angular (SPA) - but I have no experience with those technologies. Glad I could help! I'd appreciate if you accept my answer and/or upvote it. Thank you!